# Word that describes terms that exclude or divide people

Tags: single-word-requests

A few examples:

1. A creationist and an evolutionist want to save an endangered bee species. The creationist remarks about how bees were 'created' to pollinate plants. The evolutionist no longer wants to work with the creationist.
2. A man and woman are discussing how to promote equality between the sexes in the workplace. At some point, the woman complains about the 'manosphere'. This discourages the man from participating in the movement, he feels attacked by use of that term.
3. A pro-life woman and a pro-choice woman want to help out single mothers. The pro-lifer says single mothers are people that didn't 'murder' their babies. The pro-choicer sees that as an accusation, since she supports abortion as an option.

In all the examples, the word in quotes divides the people, hindering the cause. What do we call those words? In each situation, neutral language could have been used, or the word wasn't necessary to describe the cause.

If my examples are offensive to anyone, please help me improve them.

Comment: "single-word-request" always seems to divide people here.

Comment: It is very often impossible to find terminology which is "neutral" and not "offensive" to one side or the other.

Comment: *Hot-button words*. But it is not the words that have that quality; it is the people who respond to them. A particular word may be a hot-button word for Person A but not for Person B or not for most people.

Comment: I'd like to suggest that dividing people is a feature, not a bug.  Any terminology whatsoever is designed to divide people into those who are in favor, and those who are opposed.  The three examples you cite are all ones that divide two groups that might otherwise have been inclined to be allies.  We can call that "unhelpful" divisiveness.  I'd like to further suggest that, in some cases, the two groups will realize that their division is not fundamental, and devise wording that they can both live with.  In other cases, they will realize that they were never natural allies to begin with.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Within the specific contexts of these scenarios we might describe these words as controversial.  Perhaps the individual words could be described more specifically as **divisive**.  In each case, one person used **divisive language** which discouraged the other person from wanting to participate.  I would argue that the words could be considered divisive because they are often in complete contrast (to the point of being offensive) to the other person's view.

**divisive** /dɪˈvʌɪsɪv/adj. — [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/divisive)

> Tending to cause disagreement or hostility between people: *'the highly divisive issue of abortion'*

Comment: +1 for divisive. Accurate and fairly (not completely) neutral. Btw, welcome to the site. Also, love the username. :)

Comment: This is exactly the word I thought of.  By casting the problem in a way that other people who might otherwise wish to help feel that they would be abandoning their principles to do so, they *divide* the pool of people by irrelevant political position.

Comment: Divisive language does not need to always have a negative connotation though.  Sometimes divisive language is used to be hurtful, but it does not have to be used this way.  The divisive word is often the word that represents the proverbial "line in the sand".  Two people who stand on opposite sides of the line will always have one divisive point that they fundamentally cannot agree on.  "Created" vs. "Evolved", these are divisive because they describe decidedly which side of the line you stand on (generally speaking).

Answer (score 30):

We've got some very good suggestions in the other answers, but I will put forth a few more that seem particularly appropriate:

> [**polarizing**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polarizing)
>
> : causing (people, opinions, etc.) to separate into opposing groups
>
> <sub>(source: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polarizing)</sub>

or

> [**loaded (language)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_language)
>
> Loaded words and phrases have strong emotional implications and involve strongly positive or negative reactions beyond their literal meaning.
>
> <sub>(source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_language)</sub>

Comment: Good point.  Perhaps not the right term for the OP, but it can easily happen that introducing a certain term can cause a polarization that didn't exist before.

Comment: Sometimes it causes a polarization.  More often, it reveals a polarization that was always there, but hidden.

Comment: +1, "A word that describes [divisive language]" would be *polarizing*.

Comment: 'loaded' is also a suitable term in German language.

Answer (score 15):

Here's two adjectives that may be useful for the contexts you've included.

> **contentious** *adjective*: causing or likely to cause an argument; controversial. "a *contentious* issue"
>
> *synonyms*: controversial, disputable, debatable, disputed, open to debate, vexed "a contentious issue" see, Google.com [**contentious**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=contentious+de&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=contentious+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0l5.0.0.0.12919...........0.eYFDBZCHzIA&gws_rd=ssl)
>
> **coloured** *adjective*: 1.1. Imbued with an emotive or exaggerated quality: “highly *coloured* examples were used by both sides”. Oxford Dictionaries [colored/coloured](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/coloured)

Comment: +1 for **contentious** (in fact, I would split that into two answers so the two suggestions and be up- and down-voted separately)

Comment: @IQAndreas - thank you for the compliment and the good tactical advice. However, as a matter of form, I limit myself to but one answer per OP. This leaves more room for other voices. :-)

Comment: +0 (+1 + -1) Yeah I also find it hard to vote when an answer is actually two answers.  I respect your approach however I would suggest that you give more consideration to giving more than 1 answer as it may be easier and more usable for in the community at general.  I prefer multiple answers, even if from the same person to answers that contain multiple answers within them :)

Comment: @Michael Durrant - I was just awarded the "**sportsmanship**" badge, which is given for upvoting those I'm in "competition" with on the same OP---including philosowaffle's, "divisive" & Hellion's "polarizing" (but not his "loaded language" option)---upvotes are like smiles, they're free and easy to give (and they don't accrue). .

Comment: @Michael Durrant  - This is not to say I'm lacking in discrimination, but there are actually plenty of good answers, and plenty of answers that are trying to be good. **I use my upvotes to reward and encourage**. Downvotes can be useful, too, I'm more sparing with them, but I'll lob the occasional "*d-bomb*", when necessary.

Comment: "Colored" is itself a contentious word in the US, even when not referring to race.

Comment: Nice suggestion with "contentious"!

Answer (score 12):

Issues like abortion and evolution are often described as [Divisive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/divisive).

I think in the context you describe it would be acceptable to describe the language tied to those issues as divisive.

If you want to describe a situation where a minority group or an individual is being excluded, rather than one where a group is divided into factions then you might use the word [exclusionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exclusionary).

Comment: +1 for divisive. Accurate and fairly (not completely) neutral.

Comment: "divisive" is a great response to the OP's request and has, justifiably,   been the answer with the most upvotes from the beginning. Dave Magner suggested "divisive" several minutes before the other answer, so you get my upvote, Dave, and your answer is deserving of many more.

Comment: @LittleEva, good point. He'll get my vote too.

Answer (score 4):

Not a single word, but an expression I would use for this sort of situation is *"His comments **put a wedge between** them."*

Answer (score 3):

In the examples you specified I'd consider the word **partisan**, especially in examples 1 and 3, where the language used is specifically designed to separate otherwise entirely compatible people based on a single issue.

Answer (score 3):

You have some good answers here, but might I add "polemical"? It has the advantage of making you sound smart when you say it (or possibly pretentious, it could go either way depending on the audience).

> **po·lem·i·cal**
>   pəˈlemək(ə)l/
>   adjective: *polemical*
>
> of, relating to, or involving strongly critical, controversial, or disputatious writing or speech.

Answer (score 2):

Completely depending on the context, calling such words ***controversial*** can usually also be of help.

You generally want to go with ***divisive***, but in the case of this word being brought up by large groups of people and/or in frequent occasion (e.g. ***female empowerment***), controversial is generally also a strong word choice.

I would generally still use ***divisive***, though.

Comment: Unfortunately, the term *divisive* has been suggested by [two](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/236047/44619) different [users](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/236050/44619) two hours before you posted your answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I am perfectly aware of that :D I was just mentioning situations in which controversial *may* be a better word.

Comment: I get it, Think. You were "*paying your respects*" by recognizing "*divisive*" as a great term for this OP. +1, for that, and for "*controversial*", which is pretty good, too. That's a "toothy" smile you got there.  ;-)

Comment: @LittleEva Haha, thank you, I just believe that a wider choice of vocabulary can only be beneficial, hence why I created this quick note of a word I believe could be a useful substitute, in some cases.

Comment: But, of course, Think. "*Controversial*" is one of the synonyms of my "*contentious*" suggestion. That doesn't sound right! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

*Schismatic* (from the word *schism*, which refers to a divide) is applicable here, albeit not too common.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call them  **[discriminatory](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/discriminatory)** terms or language:

> - marked by or showing prejudice; biased.
> - characterized by or showing prejudice or partiality.

(TFD)

Comment: This isn't what the question is talking about.

Comment: It is, usage of discriminatory language always divide people.

Comment: Good word, bad definition.  The one you were looking for was "capable of making fine distinctions".

Comment: @Josh61 No, polarising or divisive is much better. Discriminatory would imply intent on the speaker, but the speakers in these examples could say those words without expecting the result which happened.

Answer (score 0):

*[Antagonistic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/antagonistic)*:

> adjective
>
> 1 Showing or feeling active opposition or hostility toward someone or
>   something:

Noun form: *[antagonism](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=antagonism&allowed_in_frame=0)*:

> 1797, from French antagonisme or directly from late Greek antagonisma,
>   noun of action from antagonizesthai "to struggle against" (see
>   *[antagonist](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=antagonist&allowed_in_frame=0)*).
>
> 1590s, from French antagoniste (16c.) or directly from Late Latin
>   antagonista, from Greek antagonistes "competitor, opponent, rival,"
>   agent noun from antagonizesthai "to struggle against, oppose, be a
>   rival," from anti- "against" (see anti-) + agonizesthai "to contend
>   for a prize," from agon "contest" (see *[agony](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=agony&allowed_in_frame=0)*). Originally in
>   battle or sport, extended 1620s to any sphere of human activity.
>
> *[agony](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=agony&allowed_in_frame=0)*
>
> late 14c., "mental suffering" (especially that of Christ in the Garden
>   of Gethsemane), from Old French agonie, agoine "anguish, terror, death
>   agony" (14c.), and directly from Late Latin agonia, from Greek agonia
>   "a (mental) struggle for victory," originally "a struggle for victory
>   in the games," from agon "assembly for a contest," from agein "to
>   lead" (see act (n.)). Sense of "extreme bodily suffering" first
>   recorded c.1600.

These people have divergent struggles: the *antagonism* of the issue they disagree on is a barrier to collaboration in the struggle they agree on.

Comment: Much as I like the word *antagonistic*, I don't think it is appropriate here.  One side isn't insulting the other side, they are defining a task in a way that makes the other side not wish to participate.

Comment: Then again, using terms such as "murdering babies" is certainly intended to "antagonize." +1, Scot.

Answer (score -2):

I'd call this labeling people, assigning **labels**

> [Latino High School Graduation: Defying the Odds](https://books.google.ca/books?id=xXGyoTihe_kC&pg=PA36&dq=%22labeling%20people%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=31oWVfcw0IixBK6GgrAJ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22labeling%20people%22&f=false) - Page 36
>   Harriett D. Romo - 1996
>
> There is a substantial research literature demonstrating that **the**
>   **simple act of labeling people significantly affects their behavior**.15
>   Students who are labeled "Gifted and Talented" are much more likely to
>   behave accordingly;

Comment: This is not what the question is talking about.