# What do you call a person with 'polar' views or preferences

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, adjectives

Emotionally judging things as being 'good' or 'bad'. Not in the moral sense, rather as inducing either a strongly positive or negative emotional response.

It's not 'narrow-minded' or 'prejudiced' or 'intolerant', since the person may be very open to new experiences, but most of them are either 'great' or 'horrible' afterwards with little middle ground.

Comment: Sure Mari-Lou. Learned another thing about English language today :)

Comment: Related: [Word that describes terms that exclude or divide people](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/236044/word-that-describes-terms-that-exclude-or-divide-people)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think ***[opinionated](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/opinionated)*** may convey the idea:

> - unduly adhering to one's own opinion or to preconceived notions

(M-W)

Comment: Opinionated feels about right. Thanks Josh61

Answer (score 1):

A more technical term for what you have described is [dichotomous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dichotomous):

> 1. dividing into two parts
> 2. relating to, involving, or proceeding from dichotomy

[Dichotomous thinking](http://www.democraticunderground.com/discuss/duboard.php?az=view_all&address=439x73670) is associated with various mental disorders, from [autism](http://www.php.com/how-explain-black-and-white-and-gray-thinking) to [borderline personality disorder](http://www.nimh.nih.gov/health/topics/borderline-personality-disorder/index.shtml), as well as with mood disorders such as [depression](http://www.clinical-depression.co.uk/dlp/understanding-depression/all-or-nothing-or-black-and-white-thinking-and-depression/) and a whole range of [eating disorders](http://glossary.feast-ed.org/5-psychology-and-therapies/black-or-white-all-or-nothing-thinking).

Commonly referred to as [black and white thinking](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/john-tsilimparis/stress-and-dualistic-mind_b_978230.html) or all-or-nothing thinking, psychologists define it as [splitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_(psychology)):

> Splitting (also called black and white thinking or all-or-nothing thinking) is the failure in a person's thinking to bring together both positive and negative qualities of the self and others into a cohesive, realistic whole. It is a common defense mechanism used by many people.[1](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dichotomous) The individual tends to think in extremes (i.e., an individual's actions and motivations are all good or all bad with no middle ground). *From wikipedia*

Nowadays, popular criticism of dichotomous perspectives touches on [everything](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/she-comes-long-way-baby/201506/what-is-wrong-dichotomous-thinking) from political affiliation and religious belief to gender identity and racial constructs.

Answer (score 0):

Dichotomy / Dualistic / Manichaeistic.

Comment: Hi, David. Welcome to English Language and Usage. I am not the downvoter, but let me explain something to you. It is not encouraged to post an answer without any research/reference/link that can support it. Please edit your answer after taking the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visiting our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance. If you post such a short answer, it will be flagged and deleted by democratic voting process.

Comment: I upvote because your words would have been my reply....

Answer (score 0):

How does plain old **binary** work for you?

Comment: not really well - while I could say "she's opnionated in her tastes" or even "he's dichotomous with new people", both expression sound a bit strange with 'binary'