# What's a word that means "using emotionally charged language when neutral language could be used"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

There's a great word I discovered long ago that means using emotionally charged or unfairly pejorative language to describe a situation when there is a neutral word or phrase that could communicate the idea just as easily.

This may not be the best example, but a word to describe writing "Hillary and her ***cronies***" instead of writing "Hillary and her ***advisers***". I even used it in conversation a few times, but then forgot it! So frustrating, because it's a great word that comes in *very* handy in (e.g.) political or religious debates.

Any guesses?

Comment: probably-related question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/236044/word-that-describes-terms-that-exclude-or-divide-people

Comment: hyperbole?  rhetoric?

Comment: Your examples, "cronies" and "advisers", are both nouns but your OP indicates that the word you are trying to recall is an adjective or a verb. Please clarify.

Comment: "Barbed" comments?

Comment: @PeterPoint I'm not suggesting that the word I'm looking for should be plugged in for either "cronies" or "advisers". I'm just looking for a word that would characterize using "cronies" when "advisers" would've worked just as well, and without the negative connotation.

Comment: @Hellion Thanks! Yes, that's the spirit of my search, but none of those words is exactly what I'm looking for. This was an _obscure_ word - one of those dictionary.com words of the day - and I don't think I've ever seen it anywhere else.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like it might be **dysphemism**:

> NOUN
>
> A derogatory or unpleasant term used instead of a pleasant or neutral
>   one, such as “loony bin” for “mental hospital.”
>
> The opposite of **euphemism**
>
> ([OxfordDictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/dysphemism))

This matches up pretty well with your description of "using emotionally charged or unfairly pejorative language".

Also, you mention in a comment that "This was an obscure word - one of those dictionary.com words of the day"; I'm not sure about "word of the day", but dysphemism is [number 10 on Merriam-Webster's list of "10 Fancy Words for Fancy Talk"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/fancy-words-rhetoric/dysphemism).

Comment: Thanks @1006a! I didn't have the "A-HA!" moment I expected to have when I saw your suggestion, but that honestly might be the word. At the very least, it will do for future episodes of "fancy talk" on my part :)

Answer (score 4):

Inflammatory.

Definition 2
(especially of speech or writing) arousing or intended to arouse angry or violent feelings.

"inflammatory slogans"

synonyms:   provocative, incendiary, inflaming, inciting, agitating, stirring, rousing, provoking, fomenting, rabble-rousing, seditious, subversive, mutinous;

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it is ***melodramatic*** language.

M-W:

> **[melodramatic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/melodramatic)** *adjective*
>
> : emotional in a way that is very extreme or exaggerated : extremely dramatic or emotional

Answer (score 2):

Sensationalizing

Simple Definition of sensationalize
: to describe or show something in a way that makes it seem more shocking than it really is
Source: Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary

Perhaps you are just looking for the verb "to color" in the sense of writing using a biased language in order to manipulate the readers' opinion, i.e. to propagandize.

Comment: To use "colorful language" in reference to someone's spoken language would suggest the use of profane language in British English. Might that be colourful?

Comment: Yes, Sir Peter, profanity is the most colorful of all expository styles.

Answer (score 1):

> **[Derogatory:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/derogatory)** detracting from the character or standing of something/someone.  disparaging or slanderous remarks. — Merriam-Webster

synonyms: defamatory, libelous, slanderous

> **[Ad hominem:](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ad_hominem&oldid=766369560)** Latin for "to the man" or "to the person", short for argumentum ad hominem, it is a type of logical fallacy, where during an argument or debate, you start making personal attacks directed against a person or that person's character, rather than towards the object or subject of debate or the issues at hand. 
>    — Wikipedia. Subject to the terms of the the creative commons [cc-by-sa 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). [Mirror.](http://archive.is/ZG2D5)

> **[Polemics:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/polemic)** the art or practice of engaging in controversial debate or dispute.
>                               — Oxford Living Dictionaries

Also, possibly: **Abusive language**, **Mischaracterization** (of events or a person).

And, here are a bunch of other, more esoteric words that you probably didn't mean:

> **[Denigration:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/denigration)** The action of unfairly criticizing someone or something. — Oxford Living Dictionaries

> **[Vituperation:](https://books.google.com/books?id=poacAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA632&dq=Vituperation%20%22bitter%20and%20abusive%20language%22&pg=PA632#v=onepage&q&f=false)** Bitter and abusive language. — The Oxford English Mini Dictionary, Eighth Edition

> **[Scurrilous](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/scurrilous):** Making or spreading scandalous claims about someone with the intention of damaging their reputation. — Oxford Living Dictionaries

> **[Traduce:](https://books.google.com/books?id=Vm_mNJiflwgC&lpg=PA441&dq=Speak%20badly%20of%20or%20tell%20lies%20about%20(someone)%20so%20as%20to%20damage%20their%20reputation&pg=PA441#v=onepage&q&f=false)** Speak badly of or tell lies about (someone) so as to damage their reputation
>                      — The Oxford Dictionary of Difficult Words, 2004

> **[Enmity:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ENMITY)** The state or feeling of being actively opposed or hostile to someone or something. 
>                               — Oxford Living Dictionaries

> **[Invective:](https://books.google.com/books?id=anecAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA919&dq=Insulting%2C%20abusive%2C%20or%20highly%20critical%20language&pg=PA919#v=onepage&q&f=false)** Insulting, abusive, or highly critical language. —The Oxford Dictionary of English, 2010

> **[Lambaste:](https://books.google.com/books?id=anecAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA1825&dq=%22Criticize%20(someone%20or%20something)%20harshly%22&pg=PA1825#v=onepage&q&f=false)** Criticize (someone or something) harshly — The Oxford Dictionary of English, 2010

> **[Harangue:](https://books.google.com/books?id=anecAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA798&dq=%22A%20lengthy%20and%20aggressive%20speech%22&pg=PA798#v=onepage&q&f=false)** A lengthy and aggressive speech or lecture — The Oxford Dictionary of English, 2010

> **[Vilification:](https://books.google.com/books?id=anecAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA1981&ots=TZkCbpoKDR&dq=To%20vilify%2C%20to%20make%20someone%20the%20villain%2C%20abusively%20disparaging%20speech%20or%20writing.&pg=PA1981#v=onepage&q&f=false)** To vilify, to make someone the villain, abusively disparaging speech or writing.
>                          — The Oxford Dictionary of English, 2010

> **[Antipathy:](https://books.google.com/books?id=anecAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA1981&lpg=PA1981&dq=To+vilify,+to+make+someone+the+villain,+abusively+disparaging+speech+or+writing.&source=bl&ots=TZkCbpoKDR&sig=4yeD2dGRUgAKDvJ1tbFllKMriRw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzp6zdv9PSAhXGjlQKHasRD-8Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=antipathy&f=false)** A deep-seated feeling of dislike. — The Oxford Dictionary of English, 2010

Comment: Hi Adam. These definitions do not seem to be original and [our website requires proper accreditation of the original sources when we quote others](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Also please keep in mind that due to the fact that Google is not an original resource and it returns inconsistent results, [it is not considered a valid reference here](http://preview.tinyurl.com/zhwnq6l). If you use a google define search to get definitions, you should look for the original sources. I'll edit this answer to fix the problem this time, but please remember this for the future.